# get email from User model

Tags: django

I am beginner in django and i am facing a problem that is "i want to that user can not be signup again with same email id and also username"

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user=request.POST['username']
        email=request.POST['email']
        password1=request.POST['password1']
        password2=request.POST['password2']
        if password1==password2:
            try:
                User.objects.get(username=user)
                User.objects.get(email=email)
                return render(request,"register.html",{'msg':'Please Signup with other Credentials'})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user=User.objects.create_user(username=user,password=password1,email=email)
                auth.login(request,user)
                return  redirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request,"register.html",{'msg':'Password doesn\'t matched'})
    else:
        return render(request,"register.html")
```

Comment: The `username` is already unique.

Comment: Please use a (`Model`)`Form`. This can validate uniqness.

Comment: can i do without Model form

Comment: how to get email from User model to validate the email

Comment: exactly what is the problem with a `ModelForm`? Django uses a `UserCreationForm` itself which is a `ModelForm`.